# Difference between the number of heads and tails when tossing a coin

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I know that the deviation of difference between the number of heads and tails. With this in mind, I find that the probability that the difference is exactly $k$ increases and then decreases as the number of tosses of the coin increases. Here, I could infer that for an arbitrary interval $[k,l]$, the probability that the difference is included in this interval also increases and then decreases.

However, the expression is too complicated and I do not know how to solve it, so I ask a question.

Answer (score 3):

By symmetry, the average (signed) difference between the number of heads and number of tails must be 0.  After all, if you simply interchange heads $\leftrightarrow$ tails, the mathematics is just the same.

So I'm interpreting your question to be:

- What is the expected value of the *absolute difference* between the number of heads and tails in fair coin flipped $n$ times ($n>0$)?

That answer is:

$$2^{1-n} \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor +1\right) \binom{n}{\left\lfloor
   \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor +1}$$

Here's a graph:

[image]

As expected, this number increases as $n$ increases.  After all, if you flip the coin $10^9$ times, you will (on average) get a large absolute difference between the number of heads and the number of tails.

Alternatively, if you want to know that absolute difference as a *fraction* of $n$, then simply divide the above expression by $n$.  Now we see that this expected proportional value approaches zero as $n$ gets large:

[image]

Makes perfect sense:  At extremely large $n$, the Law of Large Numbers "balances out" the number of heads and tails, so the absolute difference, divided by the total $n$, goes to zero.

Comment: You could include a graph of the average absolute difference, divided by the square root of $n$.

Comment: I was able to know that the binomial distribution roughly increases and then decreases through the fact that it approximates a normal distribution as n goes to infinity.  But I wonder if it increases and then decreases, and whether there is an intermediate oscillation part.

Comment: How can there be a peak?  There's no natural scale.

Comment: If we add up a few unimodal random variables, they may not be unimodal, in this problem there is a certain $n_0$ in the intermediate process and it increases up to that $n_0$, except that the probability itself increases at first and starts to decrease for a sufficiently large $n$. And the question is how to prove that it decreases after $n_0$.

Comment: But there is no source of *multiple* unimodal independent random variables.